# getElementByIdの結果がnullになる: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
エラーのラインはこのコードの3行目で表示されています。

コード

```
var a = param.getAttribute("a");
var b = document.getElementById(a);
var c_class = b.getAttribute("class");
```

jqueryを使用しています。

特定ユーザーのみエラーが出ているのでなんだろと思っています。
これってどういう意味になりますか？
3行目のgetAttribute関数の中身がnullって事で良いですか？？

少しコードを修正しましたが、大体このような感じです。

Comment: `b` が`null`ってことですね。 `document.getElementById(b);`は例えば`document.getElementById("b");`の間違いではないですか？

Comment: コードを修正しました。先程のbの所は間違えてました。上のvar aに入れた値を取り出している感じです。

Comment: @こばやし1 さん、編集後のコードでも同じで2行目で`b`の値が`null`に設定されているので、3行目の`b.getAttribute(...)`がエラーになっている状態です。なぜ2行目が`null`になるのかわかるような情報がないとそれ以上は何も言えないですね。

Comment: 一行目の後に```console.log(a)```を置いてみて下さい。そもそもparamにa属性はあるのですか？

Answer (score 2):

1行目のgetAttribute("a")は、paramが何か不明ですが、「a」属性の値の取得を行おうとしています。paramが要素であった場合、a属性は存在するのでしょうか？
存在しない場合、nullを返すので属性自体がないように思えます。